# How to run IPython functions within a normal Python script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I understand there are many people who are in favor of using Jupyter Notebook, powered by IPython library. I am, however, prefer to work in PyCharm and write Python script.

When I want to reduplicate codes written in Jupyter Notebook, I found sometimes they use functions from IPython. For example, this example:

```
    from fastai.vision.widgets import *

    cleaner = ImageClassifierCleaner(learn)
    cleaner
```

Here `cleaner` is a class that has widgets that can be displayed in Juypter Notebook. If I run the function in a Python script, then the widget will not be shown. I tried to fix it use the following codes:

```
    from fastai.vision.widgets import *

    cleaner = ImageClassifierCleaner(learn)
    from IPython.display import display
    display(cleaner.widget)
    plt.show()
```

It does not work. Any ideas? Thanks.

ps1: use `print(cleaner)`:

```
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=227x128 at 0x7F99C4F97470>
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=226x128 at 0x7F99C3679898>
<fastai.vision.widgets.ImageClassifierCleaner object at 0x7f99f803ec88>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jupyter widgets (and the `display` function) use JavaScript to render the output as an HTML element within the notebook page, so you can't use those in a regular Python script.  If the hang-up is that you want to be able to use PyCharm, [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html#get-started)'s how you can run a Jupyter notebook within the IDE.